# Selecting Graph Editor from Shape Keys?

Tags: shape-keys, graph-editor

I am refining a Shape Key animation but also working in Graph Editor.
Is there a way to select a Shape Key and have that specific Key highlight in the Graph Editor? Currently it does not do this so I need to select shape key then hunt down that key in graph editor, sort of a slow/impractical way to do this. Is there a setting to link them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph editor won't filter based on the selected shapekey. The [Show Only Selected](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html#view-controls) option shows all animation related to the selected objects.

There is a filter option that can help you find an fcurve in large animations. Click the magnifying glass in the header and you get a text entry to use for filtering. You can also use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>.

[image: enable filtering]

[image: sample filtering]

Comment: Thank You Sambler. Although still a little tedious for a large shape key sequence, this method does help. If anyone could write a script to link shape keys to graph editor I would have much gratitude.